# HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error when i getting data from database

Tags: java, hibernate

HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error when i gatting data from the database. The query is working fine in the console but the restclient giving thw error. Here is my code.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Patient")
public class Patient {
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int patientId;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int age;
private String cnic;
private String contactNumber;
private String homeNumber;
private String country;
private String city;
private String town;
private String streetNo;
private String houseNo;
private String email;
private String username;
private String password;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="patient", fetch=FetchType.EAGER) 
private Collection<Vitals> vitals = new ArrayList<Vitals>();




public int getPatientId() {
    return patientId;
}
public void setPatientId(int patientId) {
    this.patientId = patientId;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
public String getCnic() {
    return cnic;
}
public void setCnic(String cnic) {
    this.cnic = cnic;
}
public String getContactNumber() {
    return contactNumber;
}
public void setContactNumber(String contactNumber) {
    this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
}
public String getHomeNumber() {
    return homeNumber;
}
public void setHomeNumber(String homeNumber) {
    this.homeNumber = homeNumber;
}
public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}
public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
public String getTown() {
    return town;
}
public void setTown(String town) {
    this.town = town;
}
public String getStreetNo() {
    return streetNo;
}
public void setStreetNo(String streetNo) {
    this.streetNo = streetNo;
}
public String getHouseNo() {
    return houseNo;
}
public void setHouseNo(String houseNo) {
    this.houseNo = houseNo;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public int getId(){
    return patientId;
}

public Patient getPatient(){
    return this;
}
public Collection<Vitals> getVitals() {
    return vitals;
}
public void setVitals(Collection<Vitals> vitals) {
    this.vitals = vitals;
}
}
```

Service Class Method getting data from database:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public ArrayList<Patient> getAllPatients(){
    ArrayList<Patient> retPatient = new ArrayList<Patient>();
    try{
        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        retPatient = (ArrayList<Patient>) session.createCriteria(Patient.class).list();
        session.close();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return retPatient;
}
```

Console Output:

```
Hibernate: select this_.patientId as patientId5_1_, this_.age as age5_1_, this_.city as city5_1_, this_.cnic as cnic5_1_, this_.contactNumber as contactN5_5_1_, this_.country as country5_1_, this_.email as email5_1_, this_.firstName as firstName5_1_, this_.homeNumber as homeNumber5_1_, this_.houseNo as houseNo5_1_, this_.lastName as lastName5_1_, this_.password as password5_1_, this_.streetNo as streetNo5_1_, this_.town as town5_1_, this_.username as username5_1_, vitals2_.patient_patientId as patient8_5_3_, vitals2_.vitalId as vitalId3_, vitals2_.vitalId as vitalId7_0_, vitals2_.bpHigh as bpHigh7_0_, vitals2_.bpLow as bpLow7_0_, vitals2_.heartBeat as heartBeat7_0_, vitals2_.patient_patientId as patient8_7_0_, vitals2_.respiratoryRate as respirat5_7_0_, vitals2_.suger as suger7_0_, vitals2_.temperature as temperat7_7_0_ from Patient this_ left outer join Vitals vitals2_ on this_.patientId=vitals2_.patient_patientId
```

Can anyone tell me that what i am doing wrong here. I shall be thankful :)

Comment: this error tells you that something is wrong with server. You should look for that as the problem is not in db connection

Comment: Posting the stacktrace would help.

Comment: You should look for the exception and stack trace in the server log files.

Comment: + read something about dB normalisation

Comment: @GrigoriyDidorenko thanks there is problem in db